# Error in NSURLRequest, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I made a simple GET request with `NSURLRequest`,
here's the code:

```
let todoEndpoint: String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    let url = NSURL(string: todoEndpoint)
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }

    do {

        guard let todo = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("Error. ")
            return
        }

    print("The todo is " + todo.description)

        guard let todoTitle = todo["title"] as? String else {
            return
        }

    print("The title is " + todoTitle)

    } catch {
        return
    }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Xcode says:

[NSURLSession dataTaskForRequest:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f93d1714270

Comment: Use let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

Comment: Good catch @AnkitaShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take shared session instead of creating new one

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
```

Or you also can create own session but you must provide session configuration into constructor

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
```